# Magento 2 theme entry in core_config_data table?

Tags: magento2.2

After creating a new theme in magento 2, is new theme entry goes in core_config_data table? and what is the entry details?

Answer (score 1):

In  **core_config_data** table, check the  column **path**  mentioned as **design/theme/theme_id**

[image]

To check all the active themes, you should see

> Table : theme and theme_file .

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also where we can see active themes?

Comment: active theme also placed in same table